# Executable built with VB6 in XP mode fails to access registry in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vb6, registry, windows-xp, mode

I have successfully built an executable with Visual Basic 6 SP6 in Windows 7 XP mode. This executable fails to access registry when run in Windows 7. A build of the very same sources made in Windows 7 works fine under Windows 7. Any ideas what can be the issue?

Comment: Correction to the above: the executable when built under Windows Server 2003 works fine. VB6 cannot be installed into Windows 7.

Comment: I think you are going to need to do some heavy searching over at msdn. There can be any number of things wrong.

Comment: The operating system on which you build the application should not make any difference to how it works. Do you have UAC enabled on the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: If it's a x64 OS probably it's the SP1 of Win7 that has some troubles with ADO typelib having new GUIDs for coclasses. Don't use SP1 version to build VB6 apps or find ADO typelibs from RTM version.

Answer (score 1):

The error number would know. Why bother posting without the error number. Not real smart. Or maybe you are too stupid to read them.

Your post is a waste of time because you KNOW what the problem is (you are either turning off errors or refusing to look at the dialog with the error number printed in front of you).